# How to get and then group by date range -weekly- in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, backend, aggregation

I have a MongoDB database populated with data and I am trying to query and get the results within a certain timeframe, in this case weeks. I am querying like this, which may not be right(?), to get all objects created within the last 6 weeks:

```
let weeklyPie = await Job.aggregate([
{ $match: { createdBy: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.userId) } },
{
  $match: {
    dateCreated: {
      $gte: moment().week(-6).toDate(),
      $lt: moment().startOf('week').toDate(),
    },
  },
},
```

]);

This is supposedly returning all my jobs created within the last six weeks.

Moreover I want to group them by week so all jobs created on week say 14 (current week) are returned in a group called weekOne, jobs created on week 13 are returned in a group called weekTwo and so on for the previous six weeks starting on the current one.

This is how my schema looks like in the DB:

```
{
        "_id": "6242dc818cd686716633be36",
        "company": "Ledner Inc",
        "position": "VP Product Management",
        "status": "interview",
        "jobType": "part-time",
        "jobLocation": "San José de Feliciano",
        "dateCreated": "2022-03-27T21:24:36.000Z",
        "createdBy": "62399147d817b82f5fe8f927",
        "createdAt": "2022-02-16T04:06:46.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-07T10:51:05.171Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "interviewTime": "2022-04-20T16:30:00.000Z"
    }
```

So questions are:

1. What's the best way to get all my objects from the last six weeks? Is the snippet above correct? I am not too confident
2. How can I group them by weeks and get the whole object? Say 4 jobs were created on week 14 I want to get all 4 objects just for that week, and same with week 13 and so on.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can use `$week` and `$group`. There is a simple solution without the group names:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      createdBy: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.userId),
      dateCreated: {
        $gte: moment().startOf('week').week(-6).toDate(),
        $lt: moment().startOf('week').toDate()
      },
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "week": {$week: "$dateCreated"}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {data: "$$ROOT"}
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$data.week",
      week: {$first:"$data.week"},
      data: {$push: "$data"}
    }
  }
])
```

In order to get something similar to your expected results.
You can see how it works on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wbywDZxFkK0).

If it is important to name the groups 'weekOne', 'weekTwo', you can do it by adding a step, finding the week group name from a given list of group names:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      createdBy: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.userId),
      dateCreated: {
        $gte: moment().startOf('week').startOf('week').toDate(),
        $lt: moment().startOf('week').toDate()
      },
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "weekNum": {$week: "$dateCreated"},
      "currentWeek": {$week: ISODate("2022-04-07T21:24:36.000Z")},
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: "$$ROOT",
      weeksOrder: [
        "WeekOne",
        "WeekTwo",
        "WeekTree",
        "WeekFour",
        "WeekFive",
        "WeekSix"
      ],
      weekIndex: {$subtract: ["$currentWeek", "$weekNum"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: 1,
      weekGroup: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$weeksOrder", "$weekIndex"]}
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$weekGroup",
      week: {$first: "$weekGroup"},
      data: {$push: "$data"}
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/neO9bm9g1Xr) as well

Comment: Pfffff I mean... wow! That was so spot on. I did try with $group and my next step was try with $project as I spent hours reading the docs but didn't realise there is an $addFields option in Mongo neither. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you SOOO much! Gonna read the docs to get a better insight on what you did.

Comment: If you want, you could skip `"$addFields"` and just `"$group"` with `"_id": {"$week": "$dateCreated"}`.